# What is the difference between the `arch` field and the `llvm-target` field in Rust compiler target definitions?

Tags: rust

Rust knows about some built-in targets but also allows you to specify "my-own-target.json" files in the form of

```json
{
  "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
  "arch": "x86_64",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "64",
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "os": "none",
  "executables": true,
  "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
  "linker": "rust-lld",
  "panic-strategy": "abort",
  "disable-redzone": true,
  "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

[Possible values for arch are](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_target/spec/struct.Target.html): “x86”, “x86_64”, “arm”, “aarch64”, “mips”, “powerpc”, “powerpc64”, and others.

Possible values for `llvm-target` are [determined by LLVM](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Triple_8h_source.html).

What's the point of having both fields? Are there valid cases where you have different values for both, e.g. `x86_64-unknown-none` as `llvm-target` but  `mips` or `x86` as `arch`?

Comment: I think, the "arch" field is used also for `#cfg(target_arch = "<arch>")` compiler annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The target defines more information than `arch`. The latter only specifies the CPU architecture that should be compiled for, while the former defines much more.
From the [`clang` cross compilation reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html#target-triple):

> The [target] triple has the general format `<arch><sub>-<vendor>-<sys>-<abi>`, where:
>
> - `arch` = `x86_64`, `i386`, `arm`, `thumb`, `mips`, etc.
> - `sub` = for ex. on ARM: `v5`, `v6m`, `v7a`, `v7m`, etc.
> - `vendor` = `pc`, `apple`, `nvidia`, `ibm`, etc.
> - `sys` = `none`, `linux`, `win32`, `darwin`, `cuda`, etc.
> - `abi` = `eabi`, `gnu`, `android`, `macho`, `elf`, etc.

`x86_64-unknown-none` can only be paired with `arch=x86_64` (logically at least). Notice also that even though the above says the target is a 5-field "triple", some fields (like `abi`) are often omitted.

When given only the arch, my experience is LLVM will find a default target triple and use it for the final binary.

That said, notice that many of the field overlap with each other. E.g. `target-pointer-width` can also often be deduced from the architecture/target. So, in this specific case, I would guess most fields are there either historically, for usability, and/or redundancy.

Comment: You didn't really answer the key question: *What's the point of having both fields?*

Comment: @Shepmaster I guess I focused on the question in the title, though I added a bit of guessing to address your point.